# apple only have one distribution certificate

Tags: iphone

I have already submitted an iphone app. However, I need to do an ad hoc distribution for testing, so I revoke the distribution certificate and create and ad hoc distribution certificate. My questions is in order to submit the app, I need to revoke the ad hoc distribution again and create a new distribution certificate?

This seems to be very troublesome as after i revoke the certificate, I need to recreate the provision files again. iOs distribution portal just doesn't allow two distributions certificate to be exist. One for ad hoc and one for submitting to apple store.

Comment: Since when do you "have to" revoke your App Store distribution certification in order to create an AdHoc distribution certificate?

Comment: sorry, i think i take it wrongly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK you can have multiple multiple distribution profiles on one distribution certificate. we have one for ADHOC and one for App Store.

This link should help.
https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/distribution/index.action

Comment: i think i take it wrongly. Apple would always allow us to have one distribution certificate, but with this we can create either ad hoc provision file or provision file to submit to apple store. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

With regard to Ad hoc distribution, I had trouble finding the official answer and finally found it buried in the Apple documentation. You can now have 2 distribution certificates (I don't see a point in having more than this). The first provides you with the ability to distribute and the second can be used shortly before your first expires. Apple describes it like this: ([link](http://help.apple.com/iosdeployment-apps/mac/1.1/#app43ad802c))

> You can have two distribution certificates active at the same time; each is independent from the other. The second certificate is intended to provide an overlapping period during which you can update your apps before the first certificate expires. When requesting your second distribution certificate from the iOS Dev Center, be sure you don’t revoke your first certificate.

Comment: I can think of a reason to have more than 2 distribution certificates:  you want to allow multiple developers to build and submit apps without sharing the private key.  But, you are right, it looks like only 2 are allowed.